# How to popup a message box in SharePoint 2010

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I built a control with a RenderingTemplate for a custom ContentType. It contains additional buttons. If the code behind one button fails, I want to inform the user with a message box.

I tried

```
string script = "<script language='javascript'>MsgBox('" + errorMessage + "')</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);
```

But it doesn't show and I can't find the javascript code in the rendered page. What am I doing wrong? Is there a special SharePoint message box class in SharePoint 2010?

Comment: Is this the jQuery MsgBox or something else?  Have you tried the standard javascript alert()?  Do you get any error on the page, or is the code just not executed at all?

Comment: alert() works, thanks. But I'm looking for something similar to the SharePoint standard message boxes (like when you're trying to delete a list)

Comment: wait, I just saw, SharePoint actually uses alert() and confirm() for this ... ok, never mind ... @Peter Jacoby, if you post my snipped and replace MsgBox with alert, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like a simple change from MsgBox to alert will work for you.  So you would just need the code to slightly modified to:

```
string script = "<script language='javascript'>alert('" + errorMessage + "')</script>";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Register", script);
```